# SoapUI GroovyScript assertion within (+ or - ) 0.05 of expected values

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, assertions, numeric-ranges

I currently have the following assertion script to check the value of three fields.

```
import org.junit.Assert

def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent() 
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)              
def nodelist = xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'premium' } 
def assertions = [6.19, 6.47, 6.90]
def i=0

for (node in nodelist) assert node.toString().matches(assertions[i++].toString())
```

I am trying to get it so that the assertion will pass in the actual value is within 0.05 either side of the expected value.

The following script works when there is one value, but I am struggling to implement it with the assertion above.

```
import org.junit.Assert 
// get the xml response     
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent()     
// parse it     
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)      
// find your node by name   
def node = xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'premium' }     
// assert       
if(node.toDouble() != 0.0)  
    Assert.assertEquals(0.00, node.toDouble(), 0.05)
```

**Edit**

Sample Response:

```
<b:quote-data>
    <b:quote-data>
      <b:premium>6.13</b:premium>
    </b:quote-data>
    <b:quote-data>
      <b:premium>6.45</b:premium>
    </b:quote-data>
    <b:quote-data>
      <b:premium>6.91</b:premium>
    </b:quote-data>
 </b:quote-data>
```

Comment: Would you please show sample response that you are working on?

Comment: @Rao I have added the Sample repsonse

Comment: Thanks for the edit, so you are expecting different values?

Comment: so there is a tolerance of 0.05 between the expected and the actual. so if i expect the premium to be 6.50. the assertion should pass if the actual is between 6.45 and 6.55.

Comment: I think you already know how to handle the tolerance part, right?

Comment: Ross, can you check if the below solution helps?

Comment: By the way, you do not require to use `junit`, instead use inbuilt `assert` to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are couple of things for failure in your case.

- When you define a list as below, it considers each value type as `BigDecimal` type.
- The extracted values should be coerced to the same type before comparison.

Here is the sample to achieve the above:

```
def expectedPremiums = [6.19, 6.47, 6.90]
def xmlString = """<root xmlns:b="test">
 <b:quote-data>
       <b:premium>6.13</b:premium>
     </b:quote-data>
     <b:quote-data>
       <b:premium>6.45</b:premium>
     </b:quote-data>
     <b:quote-data>
       <b:premium>6.91</b:premium>
    </b:quote-data>
</root>"""
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
def premiums = xml.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'premium'}*.toBigDecimal()
println premiums
```

Note that using sample fixed xml, you can use to for dynamic response like you are already doing.

If you also need the logic for validation with tolerance, then use below along with above script.

```
def tolerance = 0.05
def failurePremiums = [:]
expectedPremiums.eachWithIndex { expected, index ->
   if ((expected-tolerance) <= premiums[index] && premiums[index] <= (expected+tolerance)) {
     println "${premiums[index]} is in range"
   } else {
      println "${premiums[index]} is not falling in range, failed"
      failurePremiums[expected] = premiums[index]
   }
}
assert !failurePremiums, "Not matched data(expected vs actual) :  ${failurePremiums}"
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/I0eeML)</kbd>

**EDIT: Another suggestion**

When you are using script assertion, you can change below:

From:

```
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent() 
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
```

To:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
```